# Find biggest value in vector of tuples

Tags: c++

I have a vector of tuples.

Pseudo:

```
vector<(x, x)>
```

Where the two x'es represent two different values. What I want to do is find the x with the biggest value in the whole vector.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    //Making vector
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> v;

    //Adding one random tuple to it
    v.push_back(std::make_tuple(1,50));

    //Getting biggest value in the vector
    int bufferMax = 0;
    for (auto i : v) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            int nrToTest = std::get<0>(i);
            if (j == 1) std::get<1>(i);

            if (nrToTest > bufferMax) bufferMax = nrToTest;
        }
    } 

    //Output biggest
    std::cout << bufferMax << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 1

In the first loop I loop over all tuples in the vector, than I have a second loop oscillating between the values 0 and 1. If that value is 0 I compare the first element in tuple i with the buffer, otherwise the second element in tuple i.
However, this code doesn't work as you can see at the output.

**Why doesn't this algorithm work?**

I have found another algorithm which does work (I guess)

```
  int bufferMax = 0;
    for (auto i : v) {
        //Biggest tuple value:

        int nrToTest = std::get<0>(i);
        if (std::get<0>(i) < std::get<1>(i)) {
            nrToTest = std::get<1>(i);
        }


        if (nrToTest > bufferMax) bufferMax = nrToTest;
    }
```

But I am still wondering why the first one doesn't work?

Comment: It should be `if (j == 1) nrToTest = std::get<1>(i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define the max value. In the first code snippet, you compare only the first value of each tuple:

```
int bufferMax = 0;
for (auto i : v) {  // Iterate over all elements
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        int nrToTest = std::get<0>(i); // Get the first entry in the tuple
        if (j == 1) std::get<1>(i); // This is useless: you get the second value
                                    // in the tuple but you don't do anything with it.

        if (nrToTest > bufferMax)   // You update the max, but nrToTest
                                    // is always the first value in the tuple
            bufferMax = nrToTest;
    }
}
```

The second snippet works because, at each iteration, you set the `nrToTest` to be the largest of the entries in the tuple, and then you compare it with the global maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet ( sorting by first element) works:

```
std::vector<tuple<int, int>> vec;
```

The sorting using std::max_element

```
auto result = std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::tuple<int, int>& lhs, const std::tuple<int, int>& rhs)
{
    return std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs);
});
```

Use std::tie to obtain the result:

```
int a, b;
std::tie(a,b) = *(result);
std::cout << a << "  " << b << std::endl;
```